# Installing Self Hosted Linux Agent for Azure devops Server

Tags: linux, azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent, azure-devops-pipelines

Hello Cloud Engineers,

I am trying to create a self hosted agent in azure to run by build and release pipeline.
When i am configuring the linux VM as a agent, i am getting below error.

```
--------OS Information--------
NAME="SLES"
VERSION="15-SP2"
PRETTY_NAME="SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15 SP2"
```

```
  ___                      ______ _            _ _
 / _ \                     | ___ (_)          | (_)
/ /_\ \_____   _ _ __ ___  | |_/ /_ _ __   ___| |_ _ __   ___  ___
|  _  |_  / | | | '__/ _ \ |  __/| | '_ \ / _ \ | | '_ \ / _ \/ __|
| | | |/ /| |_| | | |  __/ | |   | | |_) |  __/ | | | | |  __/\__ \
\_| |_/___|\__,_|_|  \___| \_|   |_| .__/ \___|_|_|_| |_|\___||___/
                                   | |
        agent v2.183.1             |_|          (commit b8617e6)


>> End User License Agreements:

Building sources from a TFVC repository requires accepting the Team Explorer Everywhere End User License Agreement. This step is not required for building sources from Git repositories.

A copy of the Team Explorer Everywhere license agreement can be found at:
  /home/selfhosted-linuxagent/externals/tee/license.html

Enter (Y/N) Accept the Team Explorer Everywhere license agreement now? (press enter for N) > y

>> Connect:

Enter server URL > https://hello.world.com/
Enter authentication type (press enter for PAT) >
Enter personal access token > *****************
Error reported in diagnostic logs. Please examine the log for more details.
    - /home/selfhosted-linuxagent/_diag/Agent_20210308-094413-utc.log
The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
Failed to connect.  Try again or ctrl-c to quit
Enter server URL >
```

Comment: since you are using both terms: What are you really using: Azure DevOps (cloud-hosted by Microsoft) or your self-hosted ADO Server?

Comment: self-hosted linux agent in azure devops server

Comment: And I assume a) your ADO server is accessible from the internet and b) you have read the guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops

Comment: no my azure devops organization server is not accessible from internet, i went through the documentation but did not find any thing

Comment: well I would say then either you need to put your VM on a VNET that you connect via VPN to your network or you are out of luck

Comment: @SatyamPandey Have you checked the diagnostic logs (/home/selfhosted-linuxagent/_diag/Agent_20210308-094413-utc.log)? Is there more information?

Answer (score -1):

The error may indicate the server certificate you used on your TFS server is not trusted by the build machine. Make sure you install your self-signed ssl server certificate into the OS certificate store.

```
Windows: Windows certificate store
Linux: OpenSSL certificate store
macOS: OpenSSL certificate store for agent version 2.124.0 or below
       Keychain for agent version 2.125.0 or above
```

You can easily verify whether the certificate has been installed correctly by running few commands. You should be good as long as SSL handshake finished correctly even you get a 401 for the request.

```
Windows: PowerShell Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://corp.tfs.com/tfs -UseDefaultCredentials 
Linux: curl -v https://corp.tfs.com/tfs 
macOS: curl -v https://corp.tfs.com/tfs (agent version 2.124.0 or below, curl needs to be built for OpenSSL)
       curl -v https://corp.tfs.com/tfs (agent version 2.125.0 or above, curl needs to be built for Secure Transport)
```

Check the following documentation for more details:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/certificate?view=azure-devops-2020